# Format change in Matrix Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I am trying to finish my follow matrix:
[image: Result for now]

The last thing needed is that 'Totaal Bedrag' needs to be shown with the € sign.
I tried several methods, but unfortunately it does not work.

I made a table:

```
DATATABLE (
    "Kolomtitel", STRING,
    "INDEX", INTEGER,
    "Type", STRING, 
    {
        { "jan", 0, "Maand" },
        { "feb", 1, "Maand" },
        { "mrt", 2, "Maand" },
        { "apr", 3, "Maand" },
        { "mei", 4, "Maand" },
        { "jun", 5, "Maand" },
        { "jul", 6, "Maand" },
        { "aug", 7, "Maand" },
        { "sep", 8, "Maand" },
        { "okt", 9, "Maand" },
        { "nov", 10, "Maand" },
        { "dec", 11, "Maand" },
        { "Totaal Aantal", 12, "Totaal" },
        { "Totaal Bedrag", 13, "Totaal" }
    }
)
```

This is my DAX-expression:

```
VAR GeselecteerdeKolom =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Indeling kolommen klantrapport'[Kolomtitel] )
VAR KolomType =
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        'Indeling kolommen klantrapport'[Type],
        'Indeling kolommen klantrapport'[Kolomtitel], GeselecteerdeKolom
    )

VAR Aantal = FORMAT ( [Aantal], "#,##")
VAR Omzet = FORMAT ( [Omzet], "€ #,##.00" )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        KolomType = "Maand", CALCULATE (
            [Aantal],
            Kalender[Mnd] = GeselecteerdeKolom
        ),
        GeselecteerdeKolom = "Totaal Aantal", [Aantal] , 
        GeselecteerdeKolom = "Totaal Bedrag", [Omzet] )
```

More information:
'Aantal' is the sum of the ordered amounts coming from table 'SalesRegels'.
'Omzet' is the sum of the revenue coming from table 'SalesRegels' as well

What do i have to change to make it work?

Comment: What are the columns you are using to build your matrix?

Comment: The columns are based on the datatable that is made.

Comment: I can't find the DebiteurCode, ArtikelCode, Prijs.

Comment: Those are not columns, but rows in the matrix. I don't think the error might be in there..

Comment: I did not say that the error is there. I am trying to replicate what you have done.

Comment: Aantal, Omzet from where I can get them ?

Comment: 'Aantal' is the sum of the ordered amounts coming from table 'SalesRegels'. 'Omzet' is the sum of the revenue coming from table 'SalesRegels' as well

Comment: you see ? now you are confirming to me that your question may need more info

Comment: You are right. I have added the additional information in the case.

Comment: Even the initial measure is not complete. Try to share the Anatal and Omzet measures (syntax)